# How to generate an en-dash (–) other than "--"

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am preparing a poster based on a specific template I have to use. The template uses Arial as font. Strangely, typing "--" (for example for page ranges in references) does not result in an en-dash (–), but rather two visible hyphen characters "-"'s. Is there an alternative way to generate an en-dash directly?

Comment: `\textendash`?. Though you should probably investigate why this happens.

Comment: Can't you obtain directly an endash from your keyboard? Most editors are utf8-aware nowadays.

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: I compile using xelatex

Comment: @Au101 Either `Mapping=tex-text` or `Ligatures=TeX`. The latter should be preferred.

Comment: @user3825755 You possibly have an outdated version of `fontspec`. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: TeXLive 2013, so might indeed be outdated

Comment: @PeterGrill Not exactly a duplicate. The linked answer implies that the OP was using `--` in math mode. But this is a problem with outdated `fontspec` where `--` is used in text mode. The best solution should be to just update `fontspec`.

Comment: Plaese do yourself a big favor and perform the update from TeXLive2013 to TeXLive2018.

Comment: @Mico Even in a fully up-to-date TeX Live 2018, I’ve had `--` fail in a multilingual document that used `babel`. The solution was to add `\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures = TeX }`. It’s supposed to be on by default in `fontspec`, but `\babelfont` wasn’t setting it.

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks for this. I wasn't aware of the backwardness of `babelfont` in this regard.

Comment: @Mico I should test again to see if that’s been fixed.

Comment: @user3825755 And Mico is right: you should update your installation, especially if you’d like the solutions we post here to work for you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a compilation of solutions, roughly ranked in descending order by importance. This answer incorporates information gleaned from comments below the original query -- e.g., that XeLaTeX and thus the `fontspec` package are in use.

- TeXLive2013 is seriously out of date as of February 2019. Do yourself a big favor and update your TeX distribution to TeXLive2018. An immediate benefit of performing this update is that you won't have to specify the option `Ligatures=TeX` when executing `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc. I.e., this option is now among the defaults.

  As @Davislor has pointed out in a comment, it is actually still necessary, even under the latest TeXLive distribution, to specify `Ligatures=TeX` if `babelfont` is in use. The simplest way to do this is with `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` before you load your fonts. Nevertheless, you'll come to appreciate the many small and large improvements that have occurred in TeXLive and its packages (including `fontspec`) over the past 5 years.
- When loading fonts in `fontspec`, be sure to specify the option `Ligatures=TeX`. (For TeX, creating the en-dash from `--` involves ligation.) This normally happens automatically with `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`, but not other commands such as `\newfontfamily`.  The `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` command takes care of this as well.  If you are overriding the defaults, be sure to add that, for example, `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}`.
- Write `\textendash` instead of `--`.
- If you are a glutton for punishment :-), you could write either `\char"2013` or `\symbol{2013}` instead of `--`. See [@Davislor's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472830/5001) for more information. :-)
- If you don't mind twisting your fingers into pretzel-like shapes, by all means enter the Unicode en-dash symbol directly from your keyboard. See some of the other answers for possibilities... The precise key and finger-twist combination needed to output an en-dash will depend both on the operating system (MacOS? Windows? something else?) and the national keyboard that's active.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed compilation. Yes, I should and will update my TeXLive version.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Debian Linux with a German keyboard (I know you're out there), the “*Alt Gr*” key in conjunction with the hyphen key produces the **en dash**, and the “*Alt Gr*” in conjunction with the underbar (Shift-hyphen) produces the **em dash**.

Comment: Thanks. Works well under Linux Mint. Under Windows 10 using "Alt Gr" plus the minus-sign key on the numpad produces an em-dash.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you use UTF8 encoding (either through LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or through the inputenc package) you can just type it directly into the editor.

The shortcut for the en-dash is:

"Alt+0150" for Windows

"OPT+-" for Mac

And I don't know what the shortcut is in Linux, but I'm sure you can google it and find out. Alternatively you can just copy and paste it from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an Emacs user, the following sequence of keystrokes will input the Unicode en-dash character (hex: 2013)

```
C-x 8 Return 2013 Return
```

Comment: Even easier, `C-x 8 Return en dash Return`

Answer (score 1):

With `fontspec` loaded and the TU encoding selected, you can enter either `\char{"2013}`, `\symbol{2013}` or `^^^^2013`.  There’s no real reason to type any of those instead of `\textendash`, but I mention them for completeness.